# How to get handle (hWnd) in WPF (not WinForm)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm looking for getting window handle of a WPF control (known as hWnd in Win32).

In WinForm. we can get by "core.Init(panel1.Handle.ToInt32());"

but it is impossible to do this in WPF.

//C# in WinForm
panel1.Handle.ToInt32();

//C# in WPF
???????????

Comment: Controls don't really have a hWnd in WPF, only the Window does. Why do you want to get the handle? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: WPF is windowless, there is normally just 1 hwnd for the window itself. None of the controls have a window handle. You should explain the problem of what you are trying to achieve. The answer to your question above is "no, can't do".

Comment: @TanveerBadar Purpose of getting window handle is to render graphics with my 3d engine. and need to get hWnd handle. this works in Winform but I don't know how to get hWnd in WPF. This is because WPF is way better than WInForm in my opinion so.

Comment: @Herohtar For Rendering 3D graphic with Vulkan API

Comment: Probably, I have to find another way to do this job done.

Comment: I managed a project where one of my guys did some 3d using a library and it was combined with wpf. This was a while ago and it wasn't me writing the code. I think he used this http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/michaels/2014/11/28/wpf-hwnd-adorner/

Comment: @Andy hello. I really appreciate it. I haven't tried this yet, but it looks gorgeous. I'm really happy to find this just after finding WPF has only one window. your comment must be written as answer!

Answer (score 2):

Only the window in WPF maps to a HWND.

All other element types (such as the panel) are not HWNDs internally, so you cannot get a HWND for them.

One possible solution for you would be to use a WindowsFormsHost for the part of the application you need the HWND for.

Comment: I was thinking to make a Page in WPF I think it has hWnd. I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Page doesn't have handle.

Comment: +1 for WindowsFormsHost suggestion
It does exactly what I want to solve my problem which is to serve as a host for DirectShow view.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to `Window` handler by using `WindowsInteropHelper` class like this:

```
IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(sampleWindow).EnsureHandle();
```

`EnsureHandle()` method description:

> Creates the HWND of the window if the HWND has not been created yet.

Comment: Thanks but I tried this and got this error.

CS1503, Cannot change from
'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' to 'System.Windows.Window'

I'm looking for a handle of a control (panel, button, grid and so on)

Comment: Purpose of getting window handle is to render graphics with  my 3d engine. and need to get hWnd handle. this works in Winform but I don't know how to get hWnd in WPF.

Comment: I don't know why this is not even working in my WPF project for either MainWindow and Page.